# Android Chromeium Latest Update broke PWA login with FB

Tags: android, facebook-login, chromium, progressive-web-apps

Android PWA standalone mode is unable to login with FB. Before the update you would just hit the button, there was a pop-up of fb and was returning to the PWA with access tokens but after the update it is asking which browser to open the pop-up and when you select any browsers, it opens the pop-up in that browser which resulting to turn back to PWA with no access token. The reason is access token is got by browser but PWA don't aware of it. Do you have any idea or is there anybody facing with same problem last few weeks?